# Not getting value in input field on clicking button in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, api, crud, insert-update

Simple problem. I have id and a variable I want to concatenate. However when I click on edit button it shows id in input field but not showing correspondant department name in department input field. No errors are popping up either. What is wrong?  I have problem in this line. $('#depName' + departmentId).html();

```
<table width="100%" border="0" id="tblUpdate">
    <tr>
    <td>
          Department Id:
        <input name="txtDepUpdateId" readonly type="text" id="txtDepUpdateId"  />
</td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td>
          Department Name:
        <input name="txtDepUpdateName" type="text" id="txtDepUpdateName"  />
</td>
  </tr> 
  
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark" id="btnUpdate">Update Data</button>
</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```
<script>
    var srN=0;
$(document).ready(function() {
   

    //post
    $('#btnSubmit').click(function() {
        var DepartmentName = $('#txtDepName').val();
        var obj = { "departmentName": DepartmentName };
        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/Department/InsertDepartment',
            type: "POST",
            'contentType': 'application/json',
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify(obj),
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data.result);
                if (data.result == "Inserted Successfully") {
                    srN += 1;


                    $('#tblData').append("<tr><td>" + srN + "</td><td id='depName"+ data.objectData.id +"'>" + data.objectData.departmentName + "</td><td> <button  class='btn  btn-danger btnDelete' id='delData " + data.objectData.id + "'>Delete</button> <button class='btn  btn-warning btnEdit' id='btnEdit " + data.objectData.id + "'>Edit</button> </td></tr>")
                    $('#txtDepName').val('');
                    $('#txtDepName').focus();
        
                }
                else {
                    alert(data.result);
                }
            }
        });
    })


    //update
    $('#tblUpdate').hide();
    
    $(document).on('click', '.btnEdit', function() {
        var departmentId = $(this).attr('id');
        departmentId = departmentId.replace('btnEdit', '');
        var departmentName = $('#depName' + departmentId).html();
        $('#tblUpdate').show();
        $('#tblInsert').hide();

        $('#txtDepUpdateId').val(departmentId);
        $('#txtDepUpdateName').val(departmentName);
        console.log(departmentName);
    });

    //get
    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/Department/GetAllDepartment',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            var trData = "";
            $.each(data, function(index, obj) {
                srN+=1;
                trData += "<tr><td>" + srN + "</td><td id='depName"+ obj.id +"'>" + obj.departmentName + "</td><td> <button  class='btn  btn-danger btnDelete' id='delData "+obj.id+"'>Delete</button> <button class='btn  btn-warning btnEdit' id='btnEdit "+obj.id+"'>Edit</button> </td></tr>"
                $('#tblData').html(trData);
            })
        }
    });


    
    });
  
</script>
```

Comment: ` var departmentName = $('#depName' + departmentId).html();` What's the corresponding element in HTML? I don't see it.

Comment: Please add one or more row of your table

Comment: Is the above code from your project?

Comment: It seems invalid, please add the code to the question.